# Drawing an object of NSString in a Rectangle.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to put a string in a rectangular form via `drawInRect:withAttributes:` method. The official documentation writes: "Draws the receiver with the font and other display characteristics of the given attributes, within the specified rectangle in the currently focused UIView."

This action should be done on a button event. But it doesn't work at all. Nothing is shown.
The code that I use:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // some area on the top (a part of UIView)
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);

    // my text
    NSString *str = @"Eh, what's wrong with this code?";

    // crappy attributes
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8]};

    // and finally passing a message
    [str drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Is there a particular kind of areas that might be used for drawing strings in rects? Or is it possible to draw a string in a rect where I'd like it to be? Please, help me understand it better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it doesn't work at all. Nothing is shown.

That's because no drawing context is set up when you run that code. You're looking at drawing as something that you can do whenever you feel like it, but in fact drawing is something that you should only do when the system asks you to. At other times, you should instead remember what you want to draw, and then draw it when the time comes.

When is "the time" to draw? It's when your view's `-drawRect:` method is called. Since your method is an action, it looks like you're probably trying to do the drawing in a view controller. What you want to do instead is to subclass `UIView` and override `-drawRect:` to draw what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way, you first need to make a **CGContextRef** where you will draw the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, just place everything within `drawRect`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If the down voter happens to be an expert under the iOS tag, please leave a comment so that I could improve / we could learn from each other. Thank you. @the serial down voter, who has been down voting me for weeks. Some would proclaim this is an act of cowardice, which reflects your personality and degrades the integrity of the site. While I believe one reserves the freedom of not wanting to chat with you in private, you certainly don’t believe so by trying to _subdue_ others with your down votes.

Comment: You know who **[you](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1002260/steven-penny)** are, and I do, as well. To conclude, you could further down vote me, if that’s the way how you’re used to treat others just because others do not wish to chat with you in private, because I will not accept your chat invite. Furthermore, I will not do the same to you as you have done to me with DV's, because I regard this as a shady act and this is not what this Q+A site is about.